# ASP.NET Core - MVC - Post back when Model contains List<T> with Derived classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Been struggling with this for a while...

I have:

```
public class SurveyDefinitionModel
{
    public SurveyDefinitionModel()
    { }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionBaseModel> Questions { get; set; } = new List<QuestionBaseModel>();
}

   public class QuestionMultipleRadioModel : QuestionMultipleChoiceModel {...}
   public class QuestionMultipleCheckBoxModel : QuestionMultipleChoiceModel {...}
   public abstract class QuestionMultipleChoiceModel : QuestionBaseModel{...}
   public abstract class QuestionBaseModel {...}
```

All of the rendering is fine (using Editor Templates)...
Postback Fields (via F12 debugger) look fine.....

But the List is never populated....

note: Full Project @ https://github.com/DynConcepts/variantlistpostbackMVC

Comment: Using postback's feels like a dinosaurian web forms pattern (code smell) and should be redesigned. Don't get me wrong here, but after looking through your Github repository there is little point in trying to fix this single issue when you're getting the fundamentals wrong. I'd say ditch the Web Forms way of doing things and embrace all the good that .net Core offers

Comment: @Dennis1679 - If you have an example, it would be appreciated <smile>. The code as presented is structurally from the MVC samples (except  for the list aspect especially with varying types).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the appropriate material: "Polymorphic model binding"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I need to clean up the code here, then will update the github repository.

Comment: GitHub has been updated. Set Breakpoint on Controller Method  

 public IActionResult SurveyPostback(SurveyDefinitionModel response)  

to see results of postback.